# If values are duplicate in list that values should be removed both in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

If I have list like `[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,6]` in this list both duplicate values and existing duplicate values also.

Here is my code.

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,6]
l1=[]
for i in l:
    if i not in l1:
         l1.append(i)
print(l1)
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

But,my required output should be  like this:   `[5,6]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
l=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,6]

new_l = Counter(l)
print([k for k,v in new_l.items() if v==1])
```

Output:

```
[5,6]
```

**With only loops**

```
new_list = []

for i in l:
    if i not in new_list:
        new_list.append(i)
    else:
        new_list.remove(i)

print(new_list)
```

Comment: can we write without using built in methods. only using loop concept like.

Comment: `append` is a built-in method. So is `remove`. The `in` operator invokes `__contains__`, another built-in method. `for` invokes `__iter__`. `new_list.append` and `new_list.remove` both need `__getattr__` (or something similar, I can't remember) to even recognise it's a method. And `print(new_list)` will call `__str__`. It is utterly impossible to do anything in Python "without using built in methods".

Answer (score 0):

here we can use the count method with list comprehension

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,6]
print [x  for x in l if l.count(x) == 1 ]
```

Output

```
[5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all duplicates and then build a new list without duplicates:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]

temp = set()
dupes = set()
for i in l:
    if i in temp:
        dupes.add(i)
    else:
        temp.add(i)

[i for i in l if i not in dupes]
# [5, 6]
```